# Change Directories in Intel Fortran

Tags: intel-fortran

I am trying to access a directory in which the path has some spaces.

For example, this is what is in Fortran Help:

```
USE IFPORT
LOGICAL(4) status
status = CHANGEDIRQQ('d:\fps90\bin\bessel')
```

Is it possible to change this to:

```
status = CHANGEDIRQQ('d:\fps90\bin\bessel modified')
```

I tried this and the status returns as `NAN`. Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the short name of the directory, which should b `D:\fps90\bin\bessel~1` in this case. Check with `dir /x` if unsure.

Comment: Thanks Joey. However, my case is bit complicated. I am reading this path from a file and there is possibility of having more than one space.